# Using one ethernet interface to communicate with two routers separately

Tags: networking

We have a computer that needs to communicate with two routers over one physical ethernet interface.  I know this sounds weird, but each router is actually interfaced to an Iridium L Band receiver/transmitter, and we are hoping to double our bandwidth by using two.

I would like to be able to select which link to send data over at the application level, but I'm not quite sure how to do it.  My first thought was to establish a virtual IP address in addition to the pre-configured static IP address and use two separate sockets to send() data out over each "interface" separately.  My question is, how do I make it so that only one of the routers actually routes the data out to a remote host?  The IP addresses and subnet masks of the Iridium transceivers are configurable.  Is it possible to make one transceiver only listen to the data coming from one computer IP address?  Subnets maybe?

Comment: Which OS are you using ? Are you willing to work with experimental software ?

Comment: Slackware Linux, we need absolute reliability for this application so I dont know about experimental software, but show me anyways, Im curious

Comment: I am hoping that this can be achieved within the framework of standard networking stuff :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create vlan inter faces in your machine

```
ip link add link eth0 name eth0.1 type vlan id 10
ip link add link eth0 name eth0.2 type vlan id 20
```

assign ip address to eth0.1 and eth0.2 in two networks. Later you can choose which one to bind at application level.
say like this

```
ifconfig eth0.1 192.168.10.2/24 up
ifconfig eth0.2 192.168.20.2/24 up
```

Then configure your router in two networks rather than one. Your computer and the routers should be connected to trunk port in the switch. Configure your routers to be in two networks rather than same. Configure subinterfaces in routers so that they listen for vlan 10 and 20 respectively. (how exactly to do this depends on the type of router) I can give you commands only for cisco.

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer I was looking for